# Ethereum state database persistence

Tags: evm, leveldb

Is there a way to reinstantiate a stateDB after saving the output of `state.Dump()`?

My problem is the following : I create a new StateDB object using :

```
db := ethdb.NewMemDatabase()
state, _ := state.New(common.Hash{}, state.NewDatabase(db))
```

and then execute multiple operations (`state.SetBalance(...)`) as in the statedb_test.go file.

Is it possible to recover the state object afterwards?
i.e having a persistence in the balances and accounts that were changed during the operations?

Any help really appreciated,

Thanks